# Get vector ratio between rowwise highest and second highest value in matrix

Tags: r, matrix, apply

I'm working with a matrix of probabilities, like this:

```
       [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]
[1,] 0.0002 0.3746 0.0165 0.0034 0.0274
[2,] 0.0142 0.0000 0.0005 0.0000 0.0000
[3,] 0.0000 0.0002 0.0000 0.0000 0.9847
[4,] 0.0052 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0001
```

And I'd like to get the ratio between the highest probability and the second highest in each row, which in this case would be something like:

```
13.67  # (0.3746 / 0.0274)
 28.4  # (0.0142 / 0.0005)
4923.5 # (0.9847 / 0.0002)
  52   # (0.0052 / 0.0001)
```

`RowOrder` helps me identify the number 1 and number 2 columns, but I wasn't able to advance further. Also tried using something like `apply(p_matrix, MARGIN= 1, FUN = order(decreasing = TRUE)[1:2] )` but it isn't working much.

Thank you

Comment: `order` does not sort the data, it just tells you the order of indices you need to use in order to sort the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
apply(mtx, 1, function(z) {
  z <- sort(z, decreasing = TRUE)[1:2]
  z[1] / z[2]
})
# [1]   13.67153   28.40000 4923.50000   52.00000
```

(FYI, your third example incorrectly divides 0.9847 by 0.002, it should be 0.0002 per the data.)

If you have significantly more data, then you might get a speed-up with a temp-variable and dividing once:

```r
tmp <- apply(mtx, 1, sort, decreasing = TRUE)
tmp
#        [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]
# [1,] 0.3746 0.0142 0.9847 0.0052
# [2,] 0.0274 0.0005 0.0002 0.0001
# [3,] 0.0165 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
# [4,] 0.0034 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
# [5,] 0.0002 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
tmp[1,] / tmp[2,]
# [1]   13.67153   28.40000 4923.50000   52.00000
```

(though I don't know for certain that it *will* be faster). Note that `apply(x, 1, ...)` returns a transposed matrix, ergo why we divide the first *row* by the second.

---

Data

```r
mtx <- structure(c(2e-04, 0.0142, 0, 0.0052, 0.3746, 0, 2e-04, 0, 0.0165, 5e-04, 0, 0, 0.0034, 0, 0, 0, 0.0274, 0, 0.9847, 1e-04), .Dim = 4:5)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @r2evans, now I also better get how `apply` works on R.